# SQL Server : multiple join query optimization

Tags: sql-server

I've just started with Microsoft SQL Server and I'm facing a problem, which I believe it is an sql optimization issue. Could you please take a look (see below) and give me your feedback.

I have two tables defined as follows:

```
floatTable (DateAndTime datetime2(7),
            TagIndex smallint,
            Val float)

stringTable (DateAndTime datetime2(7),
            TagIndex smallint,
            Val float)
```

The SQL query which I have used to get the RESULT is (don't laugh):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = '20130312 9:00:00'
SET @endDate = '20130313 9:00:00'

USE TensionDB

SELECT t1.DateAndTime, t1.Val AS Winch_1,t2.Val AS Winch_2, t3.Val AS Winch_3, t4.Val AS Winch_4, t5.Val AS Winch_5,
t6.Val AS Winch_6, t7.Val AS Winch_7, t8.Val AS Winch_8, t9.Val AS Latitude, t10.Val AS Longitude
FROM 
((SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime ,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 0)t1

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE ( DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 1)t2
    ON t2.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 2)t3
    ON t3.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 3)t4
    ON t4.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 4)t5
    ON t5.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 5)t6
    ON t6.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 6)t7
    ON t7.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FloatTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 7)t8
    ON t8.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime, Val FROM dbo.StringTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 8)t9
    ON t9.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime

INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DateAndTime, Val FROM dbo.StringTable 
    WHERE (DateAndTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND TagIndex = 9)t10
    ON t10.DateAndTime = t1.DateAndTime)
```

**PROBLEM**: The big problem is that even if I get the correct result, the query gets very slow for large amount of data. I'm pretty sure that there is another way to write the query, but for the moment I don't have any other idea.

Could you give me a hint please? Appreciate any help from your side.

Thank you in advance

---

@Kiril and @Patrick,

Using your hints and ideas I have re-wrote my original query using pivot table.
Unfortunately, I still have to use INNER JOIN, as the values(Val) in the *stringTable* are strings and values(Val) in *floatTable* are floats. To be honest, I have to perform more tests with both queries, as I can't see a real improvement (time wise), using pivot table; apart from the length of the query. One last thing, I have embedded the query in a stored procedure. Please find below the "final" code:

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Procedure (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the procedure.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  xxxx
-- Create date: xxxx
-- Description: retrieves tension data
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE getTension 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startDate datetime = NULL, 
    @endDate datetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT distinct pvt.DateAndTime
        , pvt.[0] AS Winch_1
        , pvt.[1] AS Winch_2
        , pvt.[2] AS Winch_3
        , pvt.[3] AS Winch_4
        , pvt.[4] AS Winch_5
        , pvt.[5] AS Winch_6
        , pvt.[6] AS Winch_7
        , pvt.[7] AS Winch_8
        , st.Val AS Longitude
        , st1.Val AS Latitude
    FROM FloatTable
        PIVOT
            (MAX(Val)
                FOR TagIndex in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
            ) as pvt
        inner join StringTable st on st.DateAndTime = pvt.DateAndTime and  st.TagIndex = 8
        inner join StringTable st1 on st1.DateAndTime = pvt.DateAndTime and st1.TagIndex = 9
    Where (pvt.DateAndTime between @startDate and @endDate)
    ORDER BY DateAndTime

END
GO
```

Thanks again for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that using pivot table is going to be more efficient:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = '20130312 9:00:00'
SET @endDate = '20130313 9:00:00'


SELECT st.DateAndTime
      , pvt.0 AS Winch_1
      , pvt.1 AS Winch_2
      , pvt.2 AS Winch_3
      , pvt.3 AS Winch_4
      , pvt.4 AS Winch_5
      , pvt.5 AS Winch_6
      , pvt.6 AS Winch_7
      , pvt.7 AS Winch_8
      , pvt.8 AS Latitude
      , pvt.9 AS Longitude
FROM StringTable st
INNER JOIN FloatTable ft on st.DateandTime=ft.DateandTime
pivot 
 ( MAX(Val) for [TagIndex] in ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9])
 order by [st.DateAndTime]
 )pvt
```

I haven't tested it so you may have to tweak it a bit, in order to make it work.

Comment: Cheers @Kiril. I guess I've got the point now. Thanks a lot all of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Start putting `DateAndTime` and `TagIndex` in an index. That would make a difference.

On the other hand, your query could get a lot faster if you wouldn't need the repeating inner joins.

Can you replace the `distinct` by a single `group by` and use `min` or `max`?

Another option is using pivot tables.

Like this:

```
select *
from   FloatTable
pivot (min(DateAndTime) x, min(Val) y in ([1],[2],[3], ...))
```

Comment: Okay. Another thought: why don't you use `pivot tables`? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I would like to add more clarifications. I forgot to mention that the DateAndTime column has been clustered indexed, which indeed improves the query. I would like to add, also, that the purpose of this query is to report the data within a time frame (max 1 day records) into a .csv file. The time frame is picked from a trend plot, having a start and an end date. I'm not sure if this would help...

Comment: I should mention that the tables and the format are not handled by me, but by a third party application.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with pivot tables yet. Anyway thanks for idea.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. I will do some research on your example.